# how to Print asp.net user controls in separate pages?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, user-controls

I have around 10 usercontrols ( each user control has textbox ,gridview) to be displayed on a single page which needs to be printed using cutepdf.

The issue is the user controls breaks into seperate page (like textbox brteaking into pages). Is there a way to print a asp.net page selectively into separate page ?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS properties `page-break-before`, `page-break-inside`, and `page-break-after` control where page breaks occur when a web page is printed from a browser.

Assuming CutePDF accurately represents the pages as they would have been printed, these should help you achieve page breaking the way you want and avoid breaking pages mid-control.

(Of course, if something, like a table, is too long for one page, a page break is inevitable.  But these CSS properties will at least give you some control over how they occur.)